# How to add QT functionality to a non-QT driver

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I have a QT application in development, which essentially is a GUI that launches programs from a few different internally developed submodules, as well as some routines developed inside this application itself. However, I've run into a roadblock. one of the submodules is developed to be able to also run as a standalone library (.a).

This library is run using a main cpp that is compiled although on the command line.

Example code for main.cpp

```
// these functions are called inside the library, but implemented in main.cpp for flexibility

void printMsg(String& msg){
    // prints/cout msg
}

int printPrompt(String& str1, String& str2){
    // it prints str1 and str2 as prompt
    // gets the user input from console that is returned as int return value
    // library uses this return value to do various task
}

main(){
    runLibApp()  // this function is in the library that starts the execution
}
```

I would like to have popups to handle the message, prompt and user input. I do have a popup function defined in the mainwindow class that is used elsewhere, but it is only called within the mainwindow class and several QT subclasses.

Since this library is not a QT subclass, I can't use my QT popup functions in them. I can't redefine the functions as part of a QT subclass without breaking the library itself.

Is there any way to be able to connect my QT popup function to this library without having to drastically rework the library?

Comment: Maybe you could run it as a separate app and doing funky things with redirecting stdin and stdout ?

Comment: Inside a QProcess you can read the output and send input to the external command line program.

Answer (score 0):

Almost right after posting, I discovered the answer myself! In  my driver cpp file, I added the standard Qt includes, as well including the mainwindow.h

In the input/output functions themselves, I added this handy function for getting the main window pointer:

```
void PrintMsg(String msg){
    MainWindow* gui = MainWindow::getMainWinPtr();
    gui->Popup(msg);
}
```

Works perfectly!